# POST request: what is name value pair of textarea?

Tags: java, android, post, textarea, http-post

I am trying to submit something in Android to Web Server I have no control over.

Its complaining that I didn't post with proper values.

I am submitting all hidden input name and value pairs.

Looking at the form, I am wondering if I am posting wrong name-value pair for .

I am posting its name, "wr_content" as name and value as text I want to post.

Am I missing something here?

### Here's HTML code for POST request:

```
<form name="fviewcomment" method="post" action="./write_comment_update.php" onsubmit="return fviewcomment_submit(this);" autocomplete="off" style="margin:0px;">
<input type=hidden name=w           id=w value='c'>
<input type=hidden name=bo_table    value='specup'>
<input type=hidden name=wr_id       value='337877'>
<input type=hidden name=comment_id  id='comment_id' value=''>
<input type=hidden name=sca         value='' >
<input type=hidden name=sfl         value='' >
<input type=hidden name=stx         value=''>
<input type=hidden name=spt         value=''>
<input type=hidden name=page        value='6'>
<input type=hidden name=cwin        value=''>
<table width=650 align=center cellpadding=3 cellspacing=0 bgcolor=#FFFFFF style="border:1px solid #DFDFDF;">
<tr><td colspan="2" style="padding:1px 0 0 5px;"></td></tr>
<tr>
<td width="13%"><center>Veil</center></td>
<td width="80%">
<textarea id="wr_content" name="wr_content" rows="6" itemname="content" required 
style='width:100%; word-break:break-all;' class=tx></textarea>
</td>
<td width=80 align=right><input type="image" src="../skin/board/jins_cate/img/btn_c_ok.gif" border=0 accesskey='s'></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

### Here's my Name-Value Pair:

```
List<NameValuePair> params2 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("w", "c"));
params2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("bo_table", "specup")); //DYNAMIC
params2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("wr_id", "337877")); //DYNAMIC
params2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("comment_id", ""));
params2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sca", ""));
params2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sfl", ""));
params2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stx", ""));
params2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("spt", ""));
params2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("page", "6")); //DYNAMIC
params2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cwin", ""));
params2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("wr_content", "hello"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to URL-encode whatever you're sending to the server. Maybe you're already doing so, this is something your submitted code example doesn't show, however.

You can have a look at this example: http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient

Comment: thanks, but I am doing proper URL-encoding. It is the problem with post request. Maybe I am missing name-value pair or is there security feature that I am unaware of?

Comment: I don't know of any security feature, especially if you're using a `DefaultHttpClient`. But I do recollect something about fishy HTTPS behaviour in given circumstances...